# Google Contacts API not retrieving contacts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-contacts-api

I am using Google Contacts API to fetch gmail contacts from my ASP.NET application.
After giving the username and password, the application doesnt respond and the connection gets timed out.
Below is the error when I tried to debug:

**Execution of request failed: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full**

Snapshot of the error
[image]

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample ? Maybe in github or codeplex

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `access_token` is valid or not. Get list of contacts as define URL :

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=" + maxemails + "&oauth_token=access_token";
```

`access_token` is provided by `Gmail`, after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your password and user is correct?
well, I will give you this code, It works fine:

---

```
public DataSet GetGmailContacts(string p_name, string e_id, string psw)
{
    //p_name = name of your app; e_id = your gmail account; psw = password of your gmail account
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn();
    dc1.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc1.ColumnName = "emailid";
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn();
    dc2.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc2.ColumnName = "name";
    dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
    RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings(p_name, e_id, psw);
    rs.AutoPaging = true;
    ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);
    Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
    int counter= 0;
    foreach (Contact t in f.Entries)
    {
        Name nombreContacto = t.Name;
        DataRow drx = dt.NewRow();
        drx["emailid"] = t.PrimaryEmail.Address.ToString();
        drx["name"] = t.Title.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(drx);
        counter++;
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    Response.Write("Total:" + counter.ToString());
    return ds;

}
```

---

After that, you can fill a Gridview with the dataSet returned by the function.